# Custom transition between Pages in WinRT

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'd like to know if there is any way to create custom animations for transitions between to `Page`s in WinRT.

Currently the only way I've found to animate the entrance of a `Page` is to add this kind of stuff in its xaml :

```
<Page.Transitions>
  <TransitionCollection>
    <PaneThemeTransition Edge="Right" />
  </TransitionCollection>
</Page.Transitions>
```

Which makes it slide in from the right. The problem is I also want the current page to slide out to the left at the same time. Currently it only disappears, leaving the screen black while the new page slides in. I also need to choose when to use the animation, depending on which page I'm coming from.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Nope, I ended up not using transition animations... Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Frame.Navigate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn279553.aspx) method.

You can use that to define the animation for a page you are navigating to by the [NavigationTransitionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.navigationtransitioninfo.aspx) class.

With fine tuning your own animations you will probably want to try build your own PageTransition using StoryBoards.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot find any info on how to use `NavigationTransitionInfo`... Microsoft's tutorial about navigation doesn't even mention it.